# Не хочет подключатся пакет gulp на Windows из за самой операционной системы как решить эту проблему?

Tags: gulp

Использую:
64-bit Windows (Windows 10)
node v16.15.0
npm v8.13.1

При глобальной установке GULP получаю один и тот же конфликт

```html
$ gulp -v
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

Пыталась решить несколькими способами а именно:
удалением

```html
C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npmи C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache
```

и глобальной переустановкой npm пакетов

второй способ:

```html
npm uninstall gulp-cli
npm uninstall -g gulp-cli
npm cache clean --force
потом
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

также настраивала параметры PATH
Ничего не помогло. Выдает все ту же ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Я удалила свои C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm и C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache переустановила глобальные модули npm, и проблема исчезла.

```html
npm uninstall gulp
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm cache clean --force
потом
npm install -g gulp
```